# MIPS: how to load the byte offset of the last element of an array

Tags: assembly, mips

[image]

[image]

do I load ((n-1) + 4)*4 as the byte offset?

how would I?

Comment: Perhaps you meant `&A[n - 1] + 4`?  Your `A[n - 1] + 4` in C would be a load from the array, and then adding to the load result.  I wouldn't describe that as adding 4 *to a byte offset*.  So it's really just `&A[n]` since `sizeof(int) == 4`

Comment: i updated with a screenshot

Answer (score 1):

They are asking you to convert `n` from an index to a byte offset.  Since these are zero-based arrays, the length, `n`, if taken as an index in the array, is (by definition of zero-based indexing) past the end of the array by 1, so the byte offset converted from `n` will be 4 past the end of the array.

Can you convert `n` from an index to a byte offset?  That is all that's needed there.

---

MIPS has only one addressing mode, which is base+displacement.  That addressing mode can add a constant to a pointer to form the effective address — and this constant should be thought of as a byte offset, since there is no opportunity to shift or multiply within the addressing mode.

If you have a pointer that is 1 index position past the end, then must also be 4 bytes past the end.  Using base+displacement where the displacement is -4 then refers to the actual last element, assuming the array has at least one element (it does because `i` is said to be within the bounds of the array).

Comment: sll $t2, $s3, 2

Comment: Very good, that's it.